# HomeButton on app Toolbar stopped working

Tags: android, performance, android-toolbar

I need HomeButton to return user to MainActivity but suddenly it stopped working. In other activities there is no such problem but code is the same.

---

### MyActivity.java

```
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("...");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_activity_webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("...");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }*/
```

---

### MyActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"></include>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_activity_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? You open an activity from MainActivity and when you press the back button the 2nd activity does not close?

Comment: Yes. I mean back button on app Toolbar.

Comment: If you press the back button at your device is it the same?

Comment: No. Device button is working. But I need button on Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default AppTheme you should already have a Toolbar. And if you set the parent activity in you AndroidManifest.xml, it should do it automatically.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <!--sets the launcher-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewActivity">
        <!--sets the parent activity-->
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity"  />
    </activity>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Navigation patterns that require you to manually specify the Back behavior in some cases.

Can be done by:

Specifying the parent activity in the manifest by adding the `android:parentActivityName` attribute the activity element.

For more detailed back navigation  with webview, check the developer site
[https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal]

Other Possibility:
If u have a menu for  that activity and have overriden,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It must have `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` for a default back navigation to work.